# custom model manager not working properly

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I was following a django tutorial about using cutom model managers and cannot figure out why this is not working.

I'm attempting to use a custom model manager to filter only posts that are marked as active in the database, so it does not show ones that are not yet finished.

model manager

```
class PostManager(models.Manager):

    def get_query_set(self):

         return super(PostManager, self).get_query_set().filter(is_active=True)
```

model

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
    body = models.TextField(blank = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = 1)
    allow_comments = models.BooleanField(default = 1)
    category= models.ForeignKey(Category)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)

    active = PostManager() #Gets just the active posts
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Then I try to filter for the active posts by using `posts= Post.active.all()`
Now, if i change this to `posts = Post.active.filter(is_active=True)` it works and filters just the active posts, but I do could this without a custom manager. Not, understanding what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in method is `get_queryset()` and not `get_query_set()` so you should be overriding `get_queryset()` and calling the parent's class `get_queryset()` method.

```
class PostManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PostManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)
```

Comment: That worked, was this changed from earlier version of Django? It used to be get_query_set. I was following an older tutorial.

Comment: I think this was changed in `Django 1.6`.